# Is there a way to log failed file operations in a linux box?

Tags: linux, logging, filesystems

I wonder if there is a log facility in linux that can be enabled to record failed file operations such as a failure in creating a directory due to permissions or in opening a file for writing so that problematic issues about the filesystem can be easily tracked.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a centralized log server and configure your syslog daemon to send all the logs (also) to that host. That way if disk errors do occur at your $someserver, then info about that might still get logged to your centralized log server. Installing & configuring such log server is trivial, for example `syslog-ng` can automatically set up a directory tree like this for you:

```
/var/log/hosts
/var/log/hosts/host1
/var/log/hosts/host2
/var/log/hosts/host3
...
```

Also the audit subsystem mentioned is excellent, but if the file system containing `/var` goes down, it does not have a place where to write unless you have a separate log server or something else set up, too.

If you truly love to tinker and love to log everything, no matter how much disk space it takes, [grsecurity](http://grsecurity.net/) has lots of additional audit features. However, grsecurity replaces SELinux, if you use that already.

Answer (score 2):

Check out **auditd**. It's a user space utilities for storing and searching the audit records generated by the audit subsystem in the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is what you need - http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/audit.html

Answer (score 0):

Personally i use strace to weed out problems like this. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174942/how-to-use-strace

> Blockquote

For example, a code that is trying to search for a file may get a ENOENT (No such file or directory) error but that may be an acceptable scenario in the logic of the code.

> Blockquote